# Random numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, noise

I am trying to make n random numbers from -0.5 from to 0.5

and I made a function like this

```
def create_noise(n)

end
```

I found an implementation of this but i don't think this works

```
 randoms = Set.new 
      loop 
       randoms << rand(max)
       return randoms.to_a if randoms.size >= n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just do

```
def create_noise(n)
  n.times.collect { rand(-0.5..0.5) }
end
```

that will spit back an array like this:

```
[-0.034680737617880486, 0.34802029078157803, 0.1346483808607455, 0.12155616615186282, -0.41043213731234474]
```